# Failure in artifact upload in Apache ACE

Tags: osgi, provisioning, apache-ace

I have seen in the documentations of ACE that one of the reasons for failure during upload of new artifacts is when type of artifact is not recognized. But what are the other reasons? For example why this error occurs even after uploading a *jar* file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Out of the box, ACE comes with support for bundles and configuration
>   files that follow the Auto Configuration specification. However, it is
>   possible to extend ACE with support for new types of artifacts. Doing
>   so requires you to do three things:
>
> 1. Write a resource processor, according to the Deployment Admin
>      specification.
> 2. Write an ArtifactHelper service implementation.
> 3. Write an ArtifactRecognizer service implementation.

https://ace.apache.org/dev-doc/adding-custom-artifact-types.html

This means that you can only upload .jars that are bundles (OSGi compliant) and configurations. Regular jars will not work unless you follow the steps described in the manual.

Hope that helps.